# Glazing for metal window in shower area

Tags: windows, wet

I have a 1950s house with a glass-brick window in the shower. In the middle of the glass brick is a metal frame with an openable frosted (not smooth) glass window.

Hopefully a straightforward question here: I need to reglaze the openable window. Other than gray color to match visually, is there any special consideration as to what type of compound to use?  Or just regular old glazing compound/putty?

[image]